# Image not showing in a table cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct, delegates

I'm new to Swift and am trying to create a table that shows an image in each of its cell, but the image is not showing.

First, I create a "Meme" struct:

```swift
struct Meme {
    var topText: String
    var bottomText: String
    var originalImage: UIImage
    var memedImage: UIImage

    init(topText: String, bottomText: String, originalImage: UIImage, memedImage: UIImage) {
        self.topText = topText
        self.bottomText = bottomText
        self.originalImage = originalImage
        self.memedImage = memedImage
    }
}
```

Second, I place `var memes = [Meme]()` in `AppDelegate`.  This is as per the tutorial's instruction.

Third, I append an instance of the struct in the following way:

```swift
    @IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        if let topText = topTextField.text, let bottomText = bottomTextField.text {

            let memedImage = generateMemedImage()
            let finishedMeme = Meme(topText: topText, bottomText: bottomText, originalImage: imageView.image!, memedImage: memedImage)
            let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [memedImage], applicationActivities: nil)
            present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
            ac.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
                if success {
                    let object = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                    let appDelegate = object as! AppDelegate
                    print(finishedMeme)
                    appDelegate.memes.append(finishedMeme)
                    return
                } else {
                    print("cancel")
                }
                if let shareError = error {
                    print("error while sharing: \(shareError.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`print(finishedMeme)` here shows that the proper data is being appended.

And, finally, I have the `ViewController`:

```swift
    var memes = [Meme]()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        memes = appDelegate.memes
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return memes.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) 
        let meme = self.memes[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView?.image = meme.memedImage
        return cell
    }
```

The app runs without crashing, except no images show on any of the cells. I do see a message in the console:

> Meme[7928:464364] [ShareSheet] connection invalidated

I've tried setting the cell at the default class `UITableViewCell` and also tried creating a custom class and assigning the reloaded data to those properties, but none seem to work:

```swift
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var memeImageView: UIImageView!

}
```

Comment: Did you do the followings?  1) print memes.count at the `numberOfRowsInSection` make sure your memes has items 2) add the constraints to custom UITableViewCell elements

Comment: `UITableViewCell` is from the default `UITableViewController`. `numberOfRowsInSection` is showing 0. This tells me that either `appDelegate.memes.append(finishedMeme)` this is not working or `let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate` this isn't working. Not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ViewController ,you have reload tableview data before adding data to your array, use below code

```
 memes = appDelegate.memes
 self.tableView.reloadData()
```

instead of

```
 self.tableView.reloadData()
 memes = appDelegate.memes
```